# Bibleref-xidx : sections for Old Testament and New Testament

Tags: indexing, bibleref

I'm planning to use `bibleref-xidx` to generate a Scripture index where the verses appear as sub-items of the chapters:

```tex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox,indextools,bibleref-xidx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\makeindex[title=Person Names Index]
\makeindex[title=Scriptural Index,name=scr,columns=1]
\renewcommand{\biblerefindex}{\index[scr]}

\begin{document}

John Doe\index{Doe}

\ibibleverse{Mk}(1:11)
\ibibleverse{Mk}(1:34)
\ibibleverse{Mk}(3:7)

\ibibleverse{Ex}(3:14)

\printindex
\printindex[scr]
\end{document}
```

[image]

In addition to that, I'd like to subdivide the index into two sections, for Old Testament and New Testament respectively.

I've tried using `\biblerefcategory{Old Testament}` and `\biblerefcategory{New Testament}`, and also with

```tex
\biblerefmap{Exodus}{1@Old Testament!01}
\biblerefmap{Mark}{2@New Testament!01}
```

but both methods seems incompatible with `bibleref-xidx` (they work with `bibleref`, but then verses are not any more sub-items of the chapters…).

Any possible workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a solution. Here a proof of concept:

```tex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{bibleref-xidx}
\usepackage{indextools}

\makeindex[title=Old Testament,name=ot,columns=1]
\makeindex[title=New Testament,name=nt,columns=1]

\newtoggle{AT}
% Switch to toggle for each book
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\br@Ex}{\toggletrue{AT}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\br@Mk}{\togglefalse{AT}}{}{}
% etc
\makeatother
% Creates two indexes
\renewcommand*{\biblerefindex}{\iftoggle{AT}{\index[ot]}{\index[nt]}}

\setindexbooktitle{Ex}{Book of Exodus}
\setindexbooktitle{Mk}{Gospel according to Mark}

\biblerefstyle{jerusalem}


\begin{document}

\ibibleverse{Ex}(1:2)
\ibibleverse{Mk}(4:7)
\ibibleverse{Ex}(5:22)
\ibibleverse{Mk}(9:12)

\printindex[ot]
\printindex[nt]

\end{document}
```

Perhaps someone has interest in it and/or can tell if the approach is solid enough.